# Unable to succussfully execute pair request from phone to Raspberry Pi

Tags: bluetooth

Android Phone -> Search for available devices -> Try to pair raspberrypi-0 -> Pop up shows on phone with certain pin.

The problem is no pop up comes up on the Raspberry Pi UI. Hence the pairing request ends up with error message `incorrect or wrong pin`

Weird thing is, if I send the pairing request from pi to the phone, I am able to pair the devices successfully. I have updated my Raspberry Pi's Bluetooth modules to the latest by running `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade bluetooth bluez-utils blueman`. I need to achieve this pairing because I am building an application to transfer data from Pi to phone using Bluetooth, which would need initiation of request from phone.

Bluetooth dongle: Bluetooth CSR 4.0 Dongle, specification 4.0 compliant. Supports profiles Networking, Dial-up, Fax, LAN access and headset.

Comment: Did you try 0000 ?  that's the most common answer to the question "I don't know my Bluetooth pin".  1234 is another common answer, but I've never actually seen any that use it, usually 0000

Comment: @Tyson somehow the pop up is not appearing for confirmation anywhere on screen from Pi.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. To get an answered for this question however, I think that your are going to need to name the exact piece of Bluetooth hardware, as well as version info for any drivers you installed.

Comment: @Tyson I added the information for hardware, but am still not sure how to get information on bluetooth drivers. Can you help me with that.

Comment: You state "I have updated my pi's Bluetooth modules to the latest."  What specifically do you mean?  What did you load from where?  Or are you simply referring to apt-get update and upgrade?

Comment: @Tyson That meant I ran `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade bluetooth bluez-utils blueman`. I updated these modules as they were required for installation of dongle.

Comment: Perfect, now update the question with that, instead of the non-specific text I previously quoted, the exact upgrade command is good since you specified modules. Then I'll step away and let someone that's done what your doing answer, I have not, but I think your questions better written now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. I was unable to do this with the GUI offered, i.e `blueman`. Instead I used the command-line interface `bluez-simple-agent`. 
For this to work correctly, you would need to make changes to file `/usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent`. Search for `KeyboardDisplay` and change it to `NoInputNoOutput`.

Comment: If you or others are looking for an automated installation on the latest raspbian jessie image that allows for auto pairing of bluetooth for a2dp and airplay. You can use this repo for the install:

https://github.com/BaReinhard/Raspberry-Pi-Audio-Receiver-Install-Car-Install